# How to display ActionView::Template::Error in my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I want to display the error message from any `ActionView::Template::Error` in my views.

I have those error messages only in my terminal like:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"transactions", :action=>"download", :id=>nil})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
begin
  ...
rescue Exception => ex
  @message = ex.message
  render "error"
end
```

error is a view containing just a single line: error.html.erb

```
<%= @message %>
```

Comment: but this will get a error in the controller, I cannot do a `begin rescue` in my view

Comment: this should be written in the controller and the controller will render the error page if the error is encountered.

Comment: the error happens in a `condition` in my view but I'll try that

Comment: I believe this should work in the view as well if written between rails tags.